# \app-theme-engine-0.5.2\res\layout\ate_preference_checkbox.xml:2: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/checkbox' for external package 'android'

Tags: java, android, gradle, aapt

BUILD ERROR: .gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6e95e6bf811482085c3edc5b16516212\app-theme-engine-0.5.2\res\layout\ate_preference_checkbox.xml:2: AAPT: warn: generated id 'android:id/checkbox' for external package 'android'.

Why this error comes with the new Android studio. No error in my code. The below code is an inbuilt XML file. How to remove this error?

(ate_preference_checkbox.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:tag="tint_accent_color" />
```